# How to check if a resource exists in an AWS S3bucket

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I have an AWS S3 bucket to which I have multiple folders.

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket =  s3.buckets['test']
bucket.exists? => true
```

Say I have a resource named `demo/index.html`, how I will check whether this resource is present in `this bucket`?

May be my question is too simple, but I am not able to find a proper answer for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**#exists? ⇒ Boolean**

> Returns true if the object exists in S3.

```
# new object, does not exist yet
obj = bucket.objects["my-text-object"]
# no instruction file present
begin
  bucket.objects['my-text-object.instruction'].exists? #=> false
rescue
  # exists? can raise an error `Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden`
end


# store the encryption materials in the instruction file
# instead of obj#metadata
obj.write("MY TEXT",
  :encryption_key => MY_KEY,
  :encryption_materials_location => :instruction_file)

begin
  bucket.objects['my-text-object.instruction'].exists? #=> true
rescue
  # exists? can raise an error `Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden`
end
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#exists%3F-instance_method

Comment: Thanks @Arsen, I should be down voted for this. I simply missed '?' in 'exists?' method. Highly appreciating your kind reply.

Comment: There's some unexpected behavior here - if the object is there, `exists?` will return `true`. But otherwise it will raise a `Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden` error! You can rescue the error and interpret that as `false`. SMH

Comment: Arsen, I posted an issue on the github repo, and the AWS team responded. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1338